# How to force load an assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, resourcedictionary

I'm trying to use resources from an external assembly:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/<name>;component/Images/Flags.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The problem is, that I constantly get the `XamlParseException` telling, that it cannot load the assembly (despite fact, that requested assembly is *in the same folder* as the asking one). Of course, the requested assembly is correctly mentioned in the `References` section.

I did a hack; created a dummy class in the requested assembly and instantiated it before `InitializeComponent()` of that control - thus forcing loading that assembly and then everything worked fine.

But how to force load an assembly in proper way? I'm sure there's some kind of sane solution for this problem...

**Alternatively**: Why WPF has trouble loading an assembly, which is correctly referenced by and is placed in the same folder as calling one?

---

I've checked, that Visual Studio tries to find the requested assembly in the following folders:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\<name>  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\<name>\<name>   
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\<name> 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\<name>\<name>  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\<name>    
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\<name>\<name> 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TemplateProviders\<name> 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TemplateProviders\<name>\<name>  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\Debugger\<name>   
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\Debugger\<name>\<name>    
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors\<name> 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors\<name>\<name>  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors\x86\<name> 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors\x86\<name>\<name>  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SharePoint\Extensions\BCS\<name>   
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\SHAREPOINT\EXTENSIONS\BCS\<name>\<name>    
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\Plugins\<name> 
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\TEAM TOOLS\PERFORMANCE TOOLS\PLUGINS\<name>\<name>  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\<name>   
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\SQLDB\<name>\<name>    
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLEditor\<name>   
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\SQLEDITOR\<name>\<name>    
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\<name>  
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\110\DAC\BIN\<name>\<name>   
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish\<name>   
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WEB TOOLS\PUBLISH\<name>\<name>    
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Project\<name>   
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\PROJECT\<name>\<name>    
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\ReferenceManager\<name>  
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\REFERENCEMANAGER\<name>\<name>   
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TailoredProjectServices\<name>   
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TAILOREDPROJECTSERVICES\<name>\<name>    
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\SQL Server Developer Tools\<name>  
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT SHARED\SQL SERVER DEVELOPER TOOLS\<name>\<name>   
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\cgiahkbv.mbu\<name>  
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\CGIAHKBV.MBU\<name>\<name>   
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\LightSwitch\v4.0\<name>   
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MSBUILD\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\LIGHTSWITCH\V4.0\<name>\<name>    
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Designers\<name> 
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\SQLDB\DESIGNERS\<name>\<name>  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\<name>  
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TEAMFOUNDATION\TEAM EXPLORER\<name>\<name>   
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\SQL Debugging\<name>   
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT SHARED\SQL DEBUGGING\<name>\<name>    
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\VsGraphics\<name>  
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\VSGRAPHICS\<name>\<name>   
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLEditor\<name>   
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\SQLEDITOR\<name>\<name>    
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\ConnectedServices\<name> 
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CONNECTEDSERVICES\<name>\<name>  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SharePoint\Extensions\ListDesigner\<name>  
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\SHAREPOINT\EXTENSIONS\LISTDESIGNER\<name>\<name>   
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Web\Razor\v3.0\<name>    
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WEB\RAZOR\V3.0\<name>\<name> 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\WindowsPhone\<name>    
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWSPHONE\<name>\<name> 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Project\<name>   
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WEB TOOLS\PROJECT\<name>\<name>    
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\<name>    
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\<name>\<name> 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\DataDesign\<name>  
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\DATADESIGN\<name>\<name>
```

But the assembly actually is in the folder:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0Exp\Extensions\<company>\<plugin>\1.0
```

Comment: Do you properly replace <Name>? Cause this is the interesting part here..

Comment: @Grumbler85 Checked that 1.0e3 times at least...

Comment: It still can be the error source.

Comment: Why is it in 12.0Exp? Isn't that the location for the Experimental Hive? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd875761.aspx

Comment: @rene It is. My project is an extension to Visual Studio and I'm currently testing it.

Comment: OK, I asked just to be sure you're not bitten by that :-)

Comment: Do you manually load any other assembly before this? If so, your load context is probably incorrect. I recall a similar issue when I worked with a VS extension.